# C# job progress calculation (progress bar)

Tags: c#

This is more of a math question but also a design question. At the risk of sounding like an idiot, I figured I would post this questions here.

I have a long running process. Inside this process, there are stages. The amount of stages are dynamic (sometimes it maybe 4 stages, other times it might be 7 total stages). I am able to get a % complete from each stage.

My question is, how do I go about calculating the overall progress? This is going to drive a simple progress indicator on an application.

The process is an external service that posts this progress out to an .net API endpoint.

Each example below is a payload I receive during the execution phase.

In C# what would the function/math look like to report the accurate progress? Seems like it should be simple and it probably is...I am just stuck.

Thank you!

```
{
  "Message": "Running simulation for insulation type: DRY, departure time (UTC): 5/11/2023 2:32:08 AM",
  "Percentage": 0.741,
  "CurrentStage": 3,
  "NumStages": 4,
  "RequestId": "7520a59b-7dc4-4878-9e3e-104ce7da451b",
  "RunFailed": false,
  "Results": null
}
```

```
{
  "Message": "Running simulation for insulation type: DRY, departure time (UTC): 5/11/2023 2:47:08 AM",
  "Percentage": 0.852,
  "CurrentStage": 3,
  "NumStages": 4,
  "RequestId": "7520a59b-7dc4-4878-9e3e-104ce7da451b",
  "RunFailed": false,
  "Results": null
}
```

```
{
  "Message": "Running simulation for insulation type: DRY, departure time (UTC): 5/11/2023 3:02:08 AM",
  "Percentage": 0.963,
  "CurrentStage": 3,
  "NumStages": 4,
  "RequestId": "7520a59b-7dc4-4878-9e3e-104ce7da451b",
  "RunFailed": false,
  "Results": null
}
```

```
{
  "Message": "Running simulation for insulation type: DRY, departure time (UTC): 5/11/2023 2:32:08 AM",
  "Percentage": 0.741,
  "CurrentStage": 4,
  "NumStages": 4,
  "RequestId": "7520a59b-7dc4-4878-9e3e-104ce7da451b",
  "RunFailed": false,
  "Results": null
}
```

```
{
  "Message": "Running simulation for insulation type: DRY, departure time (UTC): 5/11/2023 2:47:08 AM",
  "Percentage": 0.852,
  "CurrentStage": 4,
  "NumStages": 4,
  "RequestId": "7520a59b-7dc4-4878-9e3e-104ce7da451b",
  "RunFailed": false,
  "Results": null
}
```

```
{
  "Message": "Running simulation for insulation type: DRY, departure time (UTC): 5/11/2023 3:02:08 AM",
  "Percentage": 0.963,
  "CurrentStage": 4,
  "NumStages": 4,
  "RequestId": "7520a59b-7dc4-4878-9e3e-104ce7da451b",
  "RunFailed": false,
  "Results": null
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution would be to average the total progress. Since they seem to run sequentially and you have information about the stages it could look like:

`( stages_complete + current_progress ) / total_stages`

when stages_complete == total_stages, if current_progress is not 0 this equation will give a result above 1.

Comment: This was perfect. This did the trick...I should have been able to figure this out myself! Thank you very much!